# Angular Material - md-autocomplete dropdown's width

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material, md-autocomplete

I'm using `md-autocomplete` from Angular Material: [here](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/autocomplete)

It seems the dropdown's width goes with the input field's width. If an item's text is too long, there is `ellipsis`.

However, I want to show full text of an item, while keeping the input field's width relatively short. That is, the dropdown's width should expand with its content.

I tried inspecting the styles of `md-autocomplete`'s elements, but couldn't find any style that does the trick. Any idea?

**EDIT:**

Here are the style I ended up having:

```
.md-autocomplete-suggestions-container{
    overflow-y:scroll
}

.md-autocomplete-suggestions-container .md-virtual-repeat-scroller{
    position:static
}

.md-autocomplete-suggestions-container .md-virtual-repeat-sizer{
    height:0 !important
}

.md-autocomplete-suggestions-container .md-virtual-repeat-offsetter{
    position:static
}
```

However there is one more issue. The `overflow-y:scroll` always shows the vertial scroll bar even when not needed. If I change it to `overflow-y:auto`, the vertical scroll bar when present will create `ellipsis`. How do I solve this?

Comment: Can you share the code on Plunkr?

Comment: I noticed that the styles you ended up with works, but if you use the keyboard to scroll through the items, the scroll bar does not follow the selected item anymore :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use css to style `md-virtual-repeat-container`.

However, that would style **every** instance of `md-virtual-repeat-container` that you may have on your site (ie, `md-autocomplete` and `md-virtual-repeat`).

Unfortunately, there isn't an option to adjust individual md-autocomplete dropdowns at the moment. I created a [ticket and pull request](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/8393) to hopefully solve this issue. Fingers crossed that this will be included in one of the future releases of Angular Material.

Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks. Please see my edit to the original question. I now have another issue.

Comment: You can adjust `width` and `max-width` for `md-virtual-repeat-container` but it won't automatically adjust to the list of results because all the children elements are set to `position:absolute`. The simplest thing to do is set `width` and `max-width` to a desired percentage and adjust `left` to center the results. I would not recommend overriding the css to the rest of the children elements as it was written specifically to look and work a certain way. 

If you need full customization, I would recommend creating your own custom directive to get exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 10):

For anyone still facing the problem of autocomplete values being cropped because the panel width is only as wide as the field, the good news is that it has now been fixed, woohoo!

Angular Material Release [6.4.0](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) (2018-07-16) introduced the following feature,

- **autocomplete**: allow panel to have a width value of auto ([#11879](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/11879)) ([8a5713e](https://github.com/angular/material2/commit/8a5713e))

So now it's possible to just add the property panelWidth with the value auto and the panel will grow to fit the values.

```
<mat-autocomplete panelWidth="auto">
      <mat-option value="myValue">Now an option with a long label will still be readable<option>
</mat-autocomplete>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to set class on your `md-autocomplete` element so you can target it in css. See this example

```
  <md-autocomplete class="autocompletable"  
              md-min-length="0" 
              ... 
              placeholder="US State?" 
              md-menu-class="autocompletable-contents">
              <md-item-template>
                 <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><span md-highlight-text="ctrl.searchText" 
                            md-highlight-flags="^i">{{item.ok}}</span>
                        </td><td>Foo</td>
                    </tr>
                 </table>
              </md-item-template>
              <md-not-found>
                 No states matching "{{ctrl.searchText}}" were found.
                 <a ng-click="ctrl.newState(ctrl.searchText)">Create a new one!</a>
              </md-not-found>
           </md-autocomplete>
```

And then in css you need to do this

```
  md-autocomplete.autocompletable{ width: 200px; }
  .autocompletable-contents{ }
```

**EDITS**: Tested with materials 1.0.9

Answer (score 1):

I know it very late but in materials 1.1.9 you can add an attribute `md-menu-class` on the `md-autocomplete` directive.

The class you add will reported on the `.md-autocomplete-suggestions` element in the virtual repeat. So you be able to customize the css for this autocomplete only.

exemple :

```
 <md-autocomplete ...  md-menu-class="search-field-autocomplete">
```

will generate

```
<ul class="md-autocomplete-suggestions search-field-autocomplete" ... >              
    <li md-virtual-repeat="item in $mdAutocompleteCtrl.matches" ...
```

so you can customize with css like :

```
.md-autocomplete-suggestions.search-field-autocomplete {
  li {
    color: red;
  }
}
```