# Angular2 material 2 Autocomplete how to change the width of the drop down?

Tags: angular, angular-material

How to change the width of the drop down in autocomplete angular material 2? I want to make the drop down the same width as the input box.

https://plnkr.co/edit/uFS9M3?p=preview

```html
<md-input-container>
  <input class="app-searchbox-input" mdInput placeholder="How to change the width of dropdown?" [mdAutocomplete]="auto" [formControl]="stateCtrl">
</md-input-container>

<md-autocomplete #auto="mdAutocomplete">
  <md-option *ngFor="let state of filteredStates | async" [value]="state">
    {{ state }}
  </md-option>
</md-autocomplete>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add your css class to the md-container as

```
<md-autocomplete #auto="mdAutocomplete" class="app-searchbox-input">
  <md-option *ngFor="let state of filteredStates | async" [value]="state">
    {{ state }}
  </md-option>
</md-autocomplete>
```

**[Updated Plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/2xycYE?p=preview)**

Comment: Thanks. But what you have posted here does not change the width of the drop down menu the same width as the input box.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, as of July 2018, the autocomplete panel width is already the same as the input field width by default.

As per my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51395308/1195908) to a similar question, you can now use the new [panelWidth](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/api) property.

```
@Input()
panelWidth: string | number
```

> Specify the width of the autocomplete panel. Can be any CSS sizing
>   value, otherwise it will match the width of its host.