# Change the mat-autocomplete width?

Tags: angular, autocomplete, material-design

It seems like the `<mat-autocomplete>` width is always the width of the input we're typing in. Is there no way to make it larger? I have a very small input and can't read the dropdown items. I'm also limited in form space so can't make the input larger.

```
<mat-form-field style="width: 100px;">
  <input matInput [matAutocomplete]="auto">
  <mat-autocomplete style="width: 500px;" #auto="matAutocomplete">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let item of items" [value]="item">
    </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

In the document for [MatAutocomplete](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/api#MatAutocomplete) there is a property for exactly what you need:

> @Input()
>   panelWidth: string | number
>
> Specify the width of the autocomplete panel. Can be any CSS sizing value, otherwise it will match the width of its host.

By using this property you are not in the risk of meddling with anything else inherited from cdk-overlay-pane.

For further customization you might find this property useful as well:

> @Input('class')
>   classList: string
>
> Takes classes set on the host mat-autocomplete element and applies them to the panel inside the overlay container to allow for easy styling.

Comment: Thanks! I used `panelWidth="auto"` and it looks quite good.

Comment: Any idea how I can make the panel behave like with panelWidth="auto" but keep minimum width to fit the hosts width?

Answer (score 23):

Just add the panelWidth property to the mat-autocomplete

```
<mat-autocomplete [panelWidth]="300">
```

Answer (score 21):

mat-autocomplete styles are inherited from cdk-overlay-pane. In order to change width use below CSS.

```
::ng-deep .cdk-overlay-pane {
    /* Do you changes here */
      min-width:450px;
}
```

You can refer here for full example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vzetqy

Comment: `width: auto !important;` works a little better than `min-width` since it won't make the overlay large if it doesn't need to. Then you can use a `max-width` too keep it from getting to unreasonable.

Comment: @checketts' suggestion also works for the MatAutocomplete answer (Athan's), e.g. `<mat-autocomplete panelWidth="auto">`

Comment: What if you have two panels and you only want to change one of them?

Answer (score 14):

I solved it with (dynamic):

```
 [panelWidth]="'auto'"
```

Following is also possible:

```
panelWidth="auto"
```

Answer (score 7):

Apart from what Athan Soulis says, I've found out by sheer coincidence that panelWidth also accepts value "fit", which does exactly what most of us is aiming for (make it as wide as needed). Not sure it's "any CSS sizing value", but it works.

Comment: Is there a way to also have a max-width?

Comment: better to use documented `auto` value https://stackoverflow.com/a/51395308/846068

Answer (score 5):

Angular provides configuration options for autocomplete named
**MAT_AUTOCOMPLETE_DEFAULT_OPTIONS**

Documentation: https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/api#MatAutocompleteDefaultOptions

One of the field of that class is *overlayPanelClass: string*, that allow to set custom class to style *cdk-overlay-pane* for autocomplete.

1. Inject options in component that you need, through providers: [] in component declaration

```js
providers: [
        {
            provide: MAT_AUTOCOMPLETE_DEFAULT_OPTIONS,
            useValue: { overlayPanelClass: 'autocomplete-overlay' },
        },
    ]
```

2. Define your class in styles.scss

```css
.autocomplete-overlay {
    width: unset !important;
}
```

3. Set fit-content width for container, in which you display options of autocomplete, I use simplebar, so in my case it *.simple-bar-content* class

```css
.wrapper-for-simplebar {
    height: 100%;

    ::ng-deep.simplebar-content {
        width: fit-content;
    }
}
```

If you need to set fixed width use [panelWidth] = "'150px'"

Comment: I found myself coming back to this thread as I was styling cdk-overlay globally to handle this, which ended up causing a lot of problems with other things. This answer works incredibly well, and I'd suggest people try it if the other options don't work for you.

Answer (score 0):

In order for options to be same width as mat-autocomplete. You just need to set width 100% on panel and **unset** panelWidth.
Example:

```
  <mat-form-field style="width: 100%" >

    <mat-autocomplete
      #autoRef="matAutocomplete"
    >
   </mat-autocomplete>
```