# Mat-autocomplete panel should be the same width as host input, or wider depending on content

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, mat-autocomplete

I have an angular autocomplete-tree component and I have an issue with the autocomplete panel width.

I have two requirements that I can solve individually but not together:

- The panel should grow once the content is wider than the panel. I used `[panelWidth] = "auto"` for this and it works perfectly.
- The panel should have a minimum width of the host input. Can also use panelWidth for this but then I lose the functionality in the first point.

From [Change the mat-autocomplete width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49217645/change-the-mat-autocomplete-width)) I saw I can use `[panelWidth] = "auto"`.

I know I can use the css styling
`.mat-autocomplete-panel{min-width: "300px"}` but don't know how to get the width of the specific input.

So I resorted to javascript. I saw in the documentation that AutocompletePanel exposes the panel ElementRef, but this value **seems to be undefined** no matter what I do? Is the right way to acquire this value with `@ViewChild`?
I have the following code that runs on the `opened` event.

```
<mat-autocomplete #autocomplete (opened)="opened()" [panelWidth]="auto" #auto="matAutocomplete">
```

```
@ViewChild("auto") autocomplete: MatAutocomplete;
@ViewChild("autoTreeInput") autoTreeInput: ElementRef;

  opened = () => {
    setTimeout(()=>{

    let p = this.autocomplete.panel?.nativeElement; //always null because panel is undefi
    console.log("opened", p, this.autocomplete);
    if (!p ) return
    p.style.minWidth =
      this.autoTreeInput.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect().width + "px";
    },1000)
  };
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yfxr8y-dgczlt?file=app/autocomplete-simple-example.ts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The panel elementRef shows up after (not on) `opened` event is fired. More specifically, after the panel is added to the DOM. So simply adding a `setTimeout` in which I get the element works. Unfortunately this means that the element shows up with the wrong width and then jumps to the width of the input.

There might be a better solution, but this is what I'm going with now.

```
 opened = ()=> {
    let inputWidth = this.autoInput.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect().width
    setTimeout(()=>{
      let panel = this.autocomplete.panel?.nativeElement;

      if (!panel ) return
      panel.style.minWidth = inputWidth + "px";
    })
  }
```

[Working stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-autocomplete-panel-input-width-answer?file=main.ts)

Answer (score 0):

I have reviewed you stackblitz example.

It looks like is more a css issue.

Try this on `autocomplete-simple-example.css` file

```css
.example-form {
  min-width: 150px;
  // max-width <-- remove it to use 100% of width
  width: 100%;
}

.example-full-width {
  width: 100%; // add this to use all width.
  transition: width 0.5s ease;
}
.mat-focused {
  width: 270px;
}
```

A working example is here: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yfxr8y-cz1gex?file=app%2Fautocomplete-simple-example.css)

**Edit**

You can add any valid css to `width css`. In this way a have added `calc(100% - 60%)` to make it fixed same as input

```css
.example-form {
  min-width: 150px;
  width: 100%;
}

.example-full-width {
  width: 100%;
  transition: width 0.5s ease;
}
.mat-focused {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```
<mat-autocomplete (opened)="opened()" panelWidth="calc(100% - 60px)" </mat-autocomplete>
```

[Working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yfxr8y-cz1gex?file=app%2Fautocomplete-simple-example.html)

Comment: So I need the panel to be the *same* width as the <input>, or more if the content becomes wider. And this does not seem to happen in your example

Comment: Sorry, still no dice. panelWidth="calc(100% - 60px)" will make the panel 100% of the window and not 100% of the input, so resizing the input will not affect the width of the panel. Also, if panelWidth is not set to "auto", the panelWidth will not grow as content grows. Please take notice of both of the requirements in my question as I know of ways to achieve each individually but not together.